# How to repeat a VBA code through many rows using a cell in the same current row as reference

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use a code to repeat itself through many rows because it would take too much time writing one by one, i dont know if there's a code that takes from the chosen cell that i put the macro the column and row of it.

```
now in column 1 and row 1 as reference

if (current Column (1), current row (1) ) = 1 then

column number 3, current row = 1
end if

next

now in column 1 and row 2 as reference

if (current Column (1), current row (2) ) = 1 then

column number 3, current row = 1

end if
```

I wanted to copy paste to code to go on in the entire column 1, but i dont have any idea how to do that, could someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

We can **loop over rows**:

```
Sub kayky()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    N = 123
    For i = 1 To N
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = 1 Then Cells(i, 3).Value = 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

This handles 123 rows; modify to suit your data.